# Difficult system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the indeterminate system:

$a=3f$

$3b=10f+9g$

$3c=10f+10g+9h$

$3d=10f+10g+10h+9i$

$3e=10f+10g+10h+10i+9j$

$3e=-j$

EDIT: Please don't close it, I actually want to learn. This is a challenge homework problem, not standard homework. I've tried everything but it seems impossible to do by hand because it gets too messy. I might be doing it the wrong way, so I wanted to see how you guys would do it. Thanks!

This is how it was stated originally, if it helps:

$a=3f$

$3b=3a+f+9g$

$3c=3b+g+9h$

$3d=3c+h+9i$

$3e=3d+i+9j$

$3e+j=0$

Comment: I count $10$ variables and only $6$ equation. Solve for what in terms of what? There is no unique solution.

Comment: @Winther: It has an answer according to the teacher. The whole challenge was that it has more variables than equations, but he said it is solvable because he made it that way.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret: I tried substituting in equations into different ones, but it got too messy I couldn't carry on

Comment: I suggest you write is a matrix problem: $Ax = 0$ with $x=(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)$ and then rowreduce $A$

Comment: @Winther: It's too difficult, I don't even know how to use mathematica. Please help, I know you can do it

Comment: First we eliminate $a$ since its only in the first equation. Then eliminate $j$ using $j=-3e$. You are now left with $4$ equations. It is not very hard to rowreduce this matrix, it is just tedious work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** work with everything on the RHS (subtract $a$ from both sides of the first equation, $3b$ from both sides of the second equation, etc). Use [gaussian elimination](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=gauss%20elimination) with the matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}  -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 &10 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 9 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 9 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 9 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 &  0 & 0 & 0 &0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

(the problem is given half solved, if you think about it)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to post the full solution? If you have a math software it will be easier for you because I have to do it by hand. I've already tried this for literally a few hours and I want to see a solution so I can learn from it. Thanks again.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that it could possibly be enlightening to look at someone else's Gaussian elimination.